# Sending the response after all the queries have run

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async.js

I've an array made where in I've the time defined into "from" and "to" in the data array. I want to run the query for all the times to get the count from the collection and then store all of it in an array that will then be sent as response. I've been working with the async method for just the past day and I'm fairly new to it. I got the code for async by googling. This is the code in my controller

```
exports.production_report = function(req, res) {
   ShiftTiming.findOne({"clientId":req.body.clientId}, function (err, 
shiftTiming) {
     if(err)
       res.send(err);
     else{
       var data = [];
       var productionCount = [];
       for (var i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
         var from = new Date(req.body.eDate);
         from.setHours(shiftTiming.shiftA[0]+shiftTiming.shiftA[1]);
         from.setMinutes(shiftTiming.shiftA[3]+shiftTiming.shiftA[4]);

         var to = new Date(from);
         to.setHours(to.getHours() + 1);
         if (i>0) {
           from.setHours(from.getHours() + i);
           to.setHours(to.getHours() + i);
         }
         data.push({"from":from,"to":to});
       }

       async.each(data, function (user, cb) {
         async.waterfall([
           function (cb) {
             console.log(data.from);
             CycleTime.count({
               "machineId":req.body.machineId,"startDateTime":{ $gte :data.from, $lt : data.to}
            }).exec(function(err, count) {
               cb(err, count);
               console.log(count);
            });
          },
          function (count, cb) {
            cb(err, count);
          },

         ], function (err, count) {
            if(err) return callback(err);
              productionCount.push({
                count
              });
            })
      })
      res.json({
            data: data,
            productionCount: productionCount
          });
  //console.log(data);
  //res.json(data);
    }
  });
};
```

The request I send is

```
{
    "clientId":"DEMO",
    "eDate":"2018-05-23",
    "machineId":"DEMO01"
}
```

The response I send is

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T02:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T03:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T03:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T04:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T04:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T05:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T05:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T06:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T06:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T07:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T07:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T08:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T08:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T09:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T09:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T10:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T10:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T11:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T11:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T12:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T12:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T13:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T13:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T14:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T14:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T15:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T15:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T16:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T16:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T17:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T17:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T18:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T18:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T19:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T19:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T20:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T20:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T21:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T21:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T22:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T22:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-23T23:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-23T23:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-24T00:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-24T00:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-24T01:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "from": "2018-05-24T01:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2018-05-24T02:30:00.000Z"
    }
],
"productionCount": []
}
```

I simply want the count per hour and send it when everything is computed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Rather than attempting to wait for 24 counts to run, you can simply aggregate on a 1 hour interval and return all within the request day or days as required. It's much more simple and actually better performance to do so. Sometimes counts are faster, but not to this degree.

Comment: okay I'll check this out but I haven't worked with aggregate either so just curious that I don't want to have a single day as a parameter and rather have a full working day (e.g 8 AM to 8 AM + 1 day) so can I pass that as parameter? @NeilLunn

Comment: Read the big link above your question. That is what it shows you how to do.

Comment: This is the exact answer that solved my problem. For anyone with the same problem refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33275795/7709276